# Actualizar zona de la página con jQuery cada X segundos

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy haciendo una página que los estados de los productos pueden cambiar constantemente depende lo que hagan los visitantes, es decir yo puedo añadir uno producto al carrito y al otro usuario le tienen que aparecer como reservado.

Eso no pasaria hasta que los otros usuarios actualizasen la página, entonces se me ocurrió el actualizar la zona de los productos cada x segundos, el problema que tengo es que al actualizar el añadir al carrito que está hecho con jQuery no funciona.

Mi otra pregunta es, si es posible actualizar cada X segundos los productos que se encuentren con el booleano 2??

**Mi iteración de los productos**

```
@foreach ($productos as $articulos)
  <div class="card_mio">
    <div class="stl_card @if ($articulos->estado == 2) reserva @endif" id="articulo_{{ $articulos->id }}">
       @if ($articulos->subcategory_id == null)
          <a href="{{ route('web.ver_producto2', ['categoria' => $articulos->categoria->slug, 'etiqueta' => $articulos->etiqueta->slug, 'slug' => $articulos->slug]) }}" class="enlace_card"> 
       @else
          <a href="{{ route('web.ver_producto', ['categoria' => $articulos->categoria->slug, 'subcategoria' => $articulos->subCat->slug, 'etiqueta' => $articulos->etiqueta->slug, 'slug' => $articulos->slug]) }}" class="enlace_card">  
       @endif
     <div>
       <img src="{{ asset("{$articulos->foto_principal}") }}" alt="" class="img_producto">
    </div>
    </a>
     <div class="pad_info_product">
       <div class="d-flex marg_pvp">
          <div class="mr-auto pvp">{{ number_format($articulos->precio, 2, '.', '.') }}€</div>
            <div class="anadirCarrito" data-id="{{ $articulos->id }}" data-name="{{ $articulos->name }}" data-foto="{{ $articulos->foto_principal }}" data-precio="{{ $articulos->precio }}">
              <i class="fas fa-cart-plus card_mioI addCart"></i>
            </div>
           <div class="cuore_{{ $articulos->id }}">
             @if(auth()->guest())
               <a href="{{ route('login') }}" class="icono__save" data-id="{{ $articulos->id }}" id="{{ $articulos->id }}" title="{{ $articulos->name }}"><i class="far fa-heart card_mioI heart"></i></a>
             @else
             @if(in_array($articulos->id,$likes))
             <a class="icono__save disLike entrie_{{ $articulos->id }}" data-id="{{ $articulos->id }}" id="{{ $articulos->id }}" title="Eliminar favorito {{ $articulos->name }}">
             <i class="fas fa-heart card_mioI heart" style="color: #f7085e"></i>
             </a>
             @else 
             <a class="icono__save darLike entrie_{{ $articulos->id }}" data-id="{{ $articulos->id }}" id="{{ $articulos->id }}" title="Añadir como favorito {{ $articulos->name }}">
               <i class="far fa-heart card_mioI heart"></i>
              </a>
             @endif
            @endif
          </div>
       </div>
       <h2>{{Str::limit($articulos->name, 30)}}</h2>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>  
@endforeach
```

**Como actualizo la zona de la página**

```
<script>
(function($) {
    var fnConsulta = function(){
        console.log("hola");
        $(".zona_productos").load(location.href + " .zona_productos");
    };
    fnConsulta();
    timerConsulta = setInterval(function(){
        fnConsulta();
    }, 60000);
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Para probar si funciona he añadido que si tiene `estado = 2` me añada esta clase de css `reserva`

```
@if ($articulos->estado == 2) reserva @endif
```

Pero claro la función de añadir al carrito no hace nada al poner esto que se actualice.

```
$('.anadirCarrito').click(function(){

.....

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En cuanto a lo de que no funciona el carrito era tan sencillo como:

Cambiar esto:

```
$('.anadirCarrito').click(function(){
```

Por esto:

```
(".zona_productos").on('click', '.anadirCarrito',function(e)
```

En cuanto a lo otro no doy con la clave, consigo que se actualice toda la zona de `.zona_productos` pero claro si soy yo el que lo añade tiene que salir otro color y no se como hacerlo.

He probado meter en la respuesta de añadir producto al carrito el actualizar ese solo producto, pero en este caso no actualiza en los navegadores de otros usuarios.